# MS Sql synchronizing specific data

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

I am looking for some input on the current best way to synchronize specific data between two different servers.

The scenario is this; we store data for an application for numerous clients in a single database. Access to the data is controlled by its ownership (client). Now the need has arisen to allow access to a specific client's data directly via the database but on a separate server. Thus I need to synchronize only this single client's data on a scheduled basis. Is SSIS now the way to do this? It's been a while since I've needed to do something like this which I previously would have done so using DTS most likely.

Any input / examples would be greatly appreciated.

-c

Comment: May be you need to use replication ?

Comment: I have only ever used replication for entire databases. I need to synchronize only certain data not the entire database. Is this possible with replication?

Comment: Yes, you can choose desired tables when you setup replication. Quick intro - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337389.aspx

Comment: That's just it though. It's specific data within each table as it relates to one specific client.

Comment: @cra you should actually look at the link provided. It is tutorials for replication. Replication has filters you can use so you can limit the data to whatever you need.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. I will take a look at replication with filters.